# Are Exceptions Thrown when 'std::fstream' Fails to Open?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, filestream, std

Is there a way to get the `fstream` to throw an exception when it fails to open a file, and how would I do this?

I know about the `std::fstream.exceptions()` method and how to assign bits to it, but what 'bit' would throw the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iostreams can be any of three different failure states: fail, bad, and eof. The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) shows you clearly how to cause any one of those to throw an exception; by default, none of them do, but evaluating a stream object in a boolean context returns `false` if any of the failure modes have occured.

**Example:**

```
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream infile;
infile.expections(std::ios::failbit);
infile.open("foo.txt");    // throws on failure
```

Comment: But non of the resources accessible on Google actually tell if the error will be thrown when the file is being opened.

Comment: @JeroenBollen: The [open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) documentation says that the "fail" bit will be set.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file and it fails, comparing the stream such as

```
if(mystream==false)
{
//File wasn't opened properly
throw openFailed
}
```

If you detect that the stream is false, throw an exception you wrote yourself.

Comment: The problem is I need the exception object because I am mutlithreading.